# sort associative array by key

Tags: php

I want to sort associative array by key. I use ksort function but it returning 1 instead of array.Below is my code.

```
$states=array( "DD"=>"Daman and Diu", "LD"=>"Lakshdweep", "DN"=>"Dadra
and nagar haveli", "AN"=>"Andaman and Nicobar island", "SK"=>"Sikkim",
"MZ"=>"Mizoram", "GA"=>"Goa", "PY"=>"Puduchery", "CH"=>"Chandigarh",
"ML"=>"Meghalaya", "AR"=>"Arunachal Pradesh", "TR"=>"Tripura",
"HP"=>"Himanchal Pradesh", "NL"=>"Nagaland", "PB"=>"Punjab",
"CG"=>"Chattisgarh", "JK"=>"Jammu and Kashmir", "UA"=>"Uttrakhand",
"HR"=>"Haryana", "JH"=>"Jharkhand", "KL"=>"Kerela", "MN"=>"Manipur" ,
"AS"=>"Assam", "RJ"=>"Rajasthan", "MP"=>"Madhya Pradesh",
"KA"=>"Karnataka", "BR"=>"Bihar", "OR"=>"Orissa", "GJ"=>"Gujrat",
"AP"=>"Andhra Pradesh", "TN"=>"TamilNadu", "DL"=>"Delhi",
"MH"=>"Maharastra", "WB"=>"WestBengal", "UP"=>"UttarPradesh",
); 


 $states = ksort($states);
 print_r($states);
```

Output i am getting is: `1`

I want array instead of 1.

Comment: Don't figure out how functions should work: read it [in the manual](http://php.net/ksort)!

Comment: `ksort($states)` instead of `$states = ksort($states)`

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Ok I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reaffect the result of ksort to your array, ksort takes an array by reference :

```
$states=array(
"DD"=>"Daman and Diu", "LD"=>"Lakshdweep", "DN"=>"Dadra and nagar haveli", "AN"=>"Andaman and Nicobar island", "SK"=>"Sikkim", "MZ"=>"Mizoram", "GA"=>"Goa", "PY"=>"Puduchery", "CH"=>"Chandigarh", "ML"=>"Meghalaya", "AR"=>"Arunachal Pradesh", "TR"=>"Tripura", "HP"=>"Himanchal Pradesh", "NL"=>"Nagaland", "PB"=>"Punjab", "CG"=>"Chattisgarh", "JK"=>"Jammu and Kashmir", "UA"=>"Uttrakhand", "HR"=>"Haryana", "JH"=>"Jharkhand", "KL"=>"Kerela", "MN"=>"Manipur" , "AS"=>"Assam", "RJ"=>"Rajasthan", "MP"=>"Madhya Pradesh", "KA"=>"Karnataka", "BR"=>"Bihar", "OR"=>"Orissa", "GJ"=>"Gujrat", "AP"=>"Andhra Pradesh", "TN"=>"TamilNadu", "DL"=>"Delhi", "MH"=>"Maharastra", "WB"=>"WestBengal", "UP"=>"UttarPradesh"
    );

ksort($states);
print_r($states);
```

More informations about ksort [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Comment: Ok thanks for yur answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `$states = ksort($states);`.
Do `ksort($states);`.

The *sort functions directly alter the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ksort()** for sorting array by its Key

dont assign the result. Try to print after sorting as follows,

```
ksort($states);
print_r($states);
```